# Request response in django

Tags: django, server

I have question?
like if user request to the server then server process and in the processing if server gets another request then what will happen with the response

i am talking about django

Answer (score 3):

Actually, Django handles only one request at a time. It processes a single request and considers the next one only after the first request is completed.

Comment: ok untill the first request did't get the response till that it will not handle any other request.